# Socket read timeout on ajax request: any workaround?

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, timeout

I have this very long process using a web service, that I need to be launched with a single button via an ajax request, so I can display a response message when the process is done. The ajax request just calls a Zend Controller, which can be summarized this way:

```
public function myajaxAction() {
  $myModel = new MyModel();
  $someData = $myModel->fetchAll();
  foreach ($someData as $dataElement) {
    $response = call_to_remote_client($dataElement['ID']);
    echo $response;
  }
  $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
  $this->_helper->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();
}
```

The $response is then received as parameter of **success**, and can be html()'d into some response div.

It all went well for a while, but I have now discovered that if the said process takes too much time to run, my ajax request will fail, because of a 502 Bad Gateway error. Firebug tells me this happens after 5mins and 0 seconds everytime, so it does sound pretty much like a timeout.

I have found [this link](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2325335) that seems to discuss the exact same issue. It helped me identify the problem better, yet I cannot think of any solution for this. Isn't there any way to increase this timeout? I tried using stream_set_timeout() on stdout, but I clearly did not know what I was doing and therefore it clearly did not work.

Any thoughts on what are my options now?

Comment: did you try setting `set_time_limit(0)` in the Bootstrap.php ?

Comment: Apparently not. Will try that.

Comment: Tried it, same Bad Gateway error after 5 minutes.

Comment: what does your process data function do? can you post the code

Comment: Technically it is not a function, I was just trying to make the problem as simple as possible by summarizing the processing part as one generic function, but I get your point. I edited my summary to add details about the process. What I think is important is that this works perfectly fine if I break from the loop after, say, 30 turns. It outputs the results, no timeout error. And the issue cannot be an infinite loop since I am just using foreach on a finite array.

Comment: What web server are you using? 502 bad gateway indicates either that there is some kind of reverse proxy or you are using fastcgi. You'll need to alter your web server configuration to either increase the timeout for waiting on the upstream server or to increase the fastcgi timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about it for a while and since I cannot in any way increase this timeout (sysadmin said no), I had to resign and go for another option : recursive ajax call. Here is the code.

Controller:

```
public function myajaxAction() {
  $request = $this->getRequest();
  $turn = $request->getParam('turn');

  $myModel = new MyModel();
  $someData = $myModel->fetchAll(null, null, 50, $turn * 50);
  $response = array();
  foreach ($someData as $dataElement) {
    $result = call_to_remote_client($dataElement['ID']);
    $response[] = $result;
  }
  $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
  $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Ajax call:

```
var recurseajax = function(turn) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/myzend/ajax/myajax',
    data: {'turn':turn},
    success: function (data) {
      var respond = $.parseJSON(data);
      var len = respond.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        $("#responsediv").append(respond[i]);
      }
      if (len === 50) recurseajax(turn + 1);
      else $('#loading').hide();
    }
  });
};
$('#myButton').click(function (){
  $('#loading').show();
  recurseajax(0);
});
```